# allure cannot find 'webappsourcedirectory' in class org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.jettywebappcontext

Tags: java, junit, allure

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь подключить allure по этой статье [artkoshelev.github.io/posts/hello-allure](http://artkoshelev.github.io/posts/hello-allure)
после команды `mvn clean test site jetty:run` тест проходит, но валится на этапе составления отчёта, а именно ошибка `cannot find 'webappsourcedirectory' in class org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.jettywebappcontext`

Я новичок, подскажите пожалуйста, уже 2 дня пытаюсь решить эту пробему, гуглёж не помог..(
Прикладыю pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <compiler.version>1.8</compiler.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <allure.version>1.4.0</allure.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.2</aspectj.version>
    <webdriver.driver>chrome</webdriver.driver>
</properties>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        <!--scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc7.jar</systemPath-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-report-data</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.stqa.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdriver-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.43</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlelements-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compiler.version}</source>
                    <target>${compiler.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>

                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.6.16.v20140903</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopKey></stopKey>
                    <stopPort></stopPort>
                        <webAppConfig>
                            <webAppSourceDirectory>"${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin"</webAppSourceDirectory>
                        </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <resultsPattern>**/allure-results</resultsPattern>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Проблема точно на этапе составления отчёта? Что если убрать из команды jetty:run?

Comment: Проблема решилась удалением тэга <webAppConfig>. Хотел удалить вопрос, но не нашёл как это делается.

Comment: Добавь ответ, в котором описываешь решение, и пометь его как правильный